# Elasticsearch JS: Is there a way to perform highlighting after a query has been executed and hits have been returned?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have a user-searchable Elasticsearch index whose documents are returned with marked highlighting via Elasticsearch's fast-vector highlighting.

Documents in the index have access permissions by user, so when a user enters the search query "John Doe", for example, more than 10,000 hits containing matches on "John Doe" can be returned, but the list of hits must be filtered down to the top 100 documents for which the user is allowed access. So, in the end, only 100 hits are displayed to the user.

The problem is that fast-vector highlighting is performed on all 10,000 hits returned, so Elasticsearch performs expensive highlighting on 9,900 hits that in the end are thrown away.

Search speed improves drastically if we remove highlighting altogether, but we do need highlighting on this small subset of hits. Is there a way to perform highlighting after a query has been executed and hits have been returned?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `top_hits` aggregation in your search query. With that, you can specify it to return only top 100 docs with `"size": 100`. And, by default, it sorts on score, so you should get best matching docs.

And, to perform highlighting, add the `highlight` within `top_hits` aggregation.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "some-aggs": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 100,
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "<field_to_highlight>": {}
          }
        }    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For this, you would need to have the access check clause in your search query.

Ref:[ES top-hits aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)